# Non-HP transceiver and HP switch

Tags: switch, hp, sfp, transceiver

Does a non-HP single-mode transceiver work in a HP switch, and does a non-HP single-mode transceiver communicate with a single-mode HP transceiver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*from comment*

HPE switches with pre-16.x firmware require original or HP-compatible transceivers. A transceiver that's not HPE branded is not activated when inserted, as indicated by LED and in the device log. You don't necessarily need an original HPE module, there's a large "compatible" market with SFPs that electronically claim to be original.

With 16.x firmware you can `allow-unsupported-transceivers`. HPE explicitly doesn't provide support if there's a chance that your problem originates from a non-HPE module.

IEEE 802.3 Ethernet standards guarantee interoperability, regardless of vendor or brand. You can use any two 1000BASE-LX transceivers to link with each other, likewise 10GBASE-LR and so on.